# Python: why would Python stop saving in the present working directory

Tags: python, directory, save

Whenever I would save a file in Python, it would save in the present working directory. For some unknown reason, Python has stopped saving in the `pwd`.  My figures are now being saved in the directory below it.  So instead of saving in `/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes` they are now being saved in `/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics`.  My operating system is Ubuntu 13.04, I am using Emacs, and writing the program from the terminal.  When I am calling my `.py` file, the path is `emacs ~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes/stumpff.py`.  Therefore, I am in the correct directory.

What would cause this problem?  I haven't altered anything I normal do when I save a figure.

The program where this is occurred is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython                                                              
#  This program plots the Stumpff functions C(z) and S(z)                           

import numpy as np
import pylab
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


def C(z):
    if z > 0:
        return (1 - np.cos(z ** 0.5)) / z
    elif z < 0:
        return (np.cosh(np.sqrt(-z)) - 1) / -z
    return 0.5


def S(z):
    if z > 0:
        return (np.sqrt(z) - np.sin(z ** 0.5)) / np.sqrt(z) ** 3
    elif z < 0:
        return (np.sinh(np.sqrt(-z)) - np.sqrt(-z)) / np.sqrt(-z) ** 3
    return 1.0 / 6.0


vC = np.vectorize(C)
vS = np.vectorize(S)

z = np.linspace(-50.0, 500.0, 500000.0)
y = vC(z)
y2 = vS(z)

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(z, y, 'r')
ax.plot(z, y2, 'b')
pylab.legend(('$C(z)$', '$S(z)$'), loc = 0)
pylab.xlim((-50, 0))
pylab.ylim((0, 15))
pylab.xlabel('$z$')
pylab.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
pylab.savefig('stumpffneg50to0.eps', format = 'eps')
```

**Edit:**

Previously, when I saved a figure, the figure would save in the directory where the `.py` file was located even if I wasn't in that directory.  That is, I could be in the home directory, run the file in `emacs`, and the file would be where I wanted it to save.  Now, this isn't the case even though the file used to always save in the location of the python script.

If I run the file from the terminal as `ipython ~/path/to/file`, the figures will save where the `.py` file is located.

If I open the file in `emacs` and use `C-c C-c` to run the file, the files will save one level down from the directory the `.py` file is in.

If I cd to the directory then open the file in `emacs`, the file again will save one level down.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me (OS X, running from terminal). Are you running this from inside Emacs? If so, what happens if you run it from the terminal, while in the exact directory you want the file to be saved in? What happens if you switch from ipython to python?

Comment: @cge I am running it from within the terminal.  This is the first time this has happened.  If I run it as `ipython path/to/file`, then it saves in the correct dir.

Comment: When you start a script, it does not `cd` to the directory the script is in. For example, if you `cd ~/foo`, then `python ~/bar/baz.py`, the current working directory for that script is still `~/foo`, not `~/bar`.

Comment: @abarnert python has being saving in the correct directory that the file was created in from the time I have been using python except for this one script though.

Comment: @dustin: If you've been running scripts that are in your current working directory, and now you've done a `cd`, or this script is in a different directory than the others, then you will get a different result. That's not because Python is doing anything wrong; that's how "current working directory" works.

Comment: @abarnert I understand what you are saying but this has never happened before when I saved a figured. Regardless of what directory I was in, when I saved the figures before, the figures always saved in the location of the `py` file.  This not saving the correct directory where the `py` file just started with the current script whereas I have numerous others that worked the other even when I was in my home directory.

Comment: If the files were being saved in the same directory as the `py` file, even though that directory wasn't the current directory, and you weren't doing anything to make that happen… something was very wrong. The way it's working now it's the way it's supposed to. Relative paths are relative to the cwd, and the cwd is the shell's cwd when it launches the Python interpreter, not the script's directory.

Comment: @abarnert since it is working correctly now, is there a command I can add to achieve the result I desire?

Comment: @dustin: You can run the script with, e.g., `$(cd ~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes; ./stumpff.py)` instead of just `~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes/stumpff.py`, or write a wrapper that does `$(cd $(dirname $1); $(basename $1))`. Or you could change your Python code to `os.chdir(os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]))`, or explicitly use paths off `sys.argv[1]` instead of relative paths, …

Comment: @abarnert can you make an answer with your past comments so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start Python, it inherits its current working directory from the shell. So, for example:

```
$ cd ~
$ ~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes/stumpff.py
```

In this case, the current working directory is `~`, not `~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes/`.

This means that any relative paths are relative to `~`, so if you just create a file named `foo.data`, it ends up as `~/foo.data`.

So, what if you want to get files into paths like `~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes/foo.data`? There are two basic ways to do it—either set the cwd to the script path, or use the script path explicitly. And there are two ways to do the first part, from outside or inside of the Python script. And… well, let's just go over all the variations one by one.

---

If you want to launch the script from its own working directory, you can of course manually `cd` to that directory first, or you can write a bash alias or function or script that does something like:

```
$(cd $(dirname $1) ./$(basename $1))
```

Obviously you'll want to get a bit fancier if you want to pass multiple arguments, or if you want to be able to use it on `python  ~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes/stumpff.py` instead of just `~/Documents/.../OrbitalMechanics/OrbitalNotes/stumpff.py` so the script is `$2`, etc. But it's all basic sh stuff from here.

---

If you want the script to change its own working directory, you can do that at the start of the script:

```
import os
import sys

scriptpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(scriptpath)
```

(In some cases, you might want to use `sys.argv[1]` instead of `__file__`, but the details are hard to explain. If you want to learn, you can read the docs for each. If you don't want to learn, and you run into a problem, print out `__file__` and see if it looks right, and, if not, try the other one.)

---

Or, you can just explicitly use `scriptpath` as a base instead of using cwd-relative paths. In this case, you'll probably want to use the *absolute* path to your script as a base (so later calls to `chdir` won't affect you):

```
import os
import sys

scriptpath = os.path.abspath(os.dirname(__file__))

# ...

datapath = os.path.join(scriptpath, 'foo.data')
with open(datapath, 'w') as datafile:
    # ...
```